# Basic Java EE Web app

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to Java EE web app development.
Can anyone tell me basic code to go from JSP page to servlet to another JSP page.

for example, login JSP submit button takes me to Servlet and performs some function and redirects to another JSP.

Comment: i am also a learner too but I'll help you. Meanwhile go through these excellent resource for starters : read some basic material on [**Servlets**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-overview.htm) and [**JSP**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_tutorial.pdf).They are perfect place for starters. If still it doesn't help consider watching the video Tutorial. I recommend one by **JavaBrains** on YouTube.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b42CJ0r-1to&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to J2EE Web Development world.
**ANS 01** : Yes, I will try to tell you basic code to go from JSP page to servlet to another JSP page by giving an example.

---

**login.jsp**

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
      First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name"> <br/> 
      Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"/> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Here, using the attribute `action` of HTML tag `<form>` we instruct (upon pressing Submit button) to go to the corresponding mapped servlet? which servlet? That servlet which catches "login" using annotations. (Read more about annotations here : [servlet mapping annotation](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/jsp-servlet-hello-world-example.html)).So, it is caught by `LoginServlet.java`

**LoginServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "Login Servlet",
            description = "this page checks if the user is authenticated",
            urlPatterns = "/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {

    // login JSP submit button has brought you to Servlet 
    // where you can perform some function using Service classes


    //redirecting to another page : 2 ways

    /* Method 01 */
    response.sendRedirect("desired.jsp");

    /* Method 02 */
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("desired.jsp").forward(request, response); 
    }//end of doGet()

}//end of LoginServlet Class
```

Further, when to use `sendRedirect` and `getRequestDispatcher` is yet another question. These methods have its own advantages/limitations.

Comment: Very nice explanation, just a small correction, is doPost method that gets called not doGet. cheers